# Excel formula - find chacter in string, delete characters at end of string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column that displays a catalogue reference of stock received. Where more than 1 box of stock is received the catalogue number has a suffix '(BX (plus the number of boxes))'

e.g.

Catalogue ref 'ABC123' with 3 boxes would be 'ABC123(BX3)'

Catalogue ref 'DEF456' with 12 boxes would be 'DEF456(BX12)'

I use the following formula to identify which catalogue references have multiple boxes ...

```
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("(BX",C2))
```

... this formula is copied down in column H for all rows.

Is there a way to remove the box information from catalogue reference ?

e.g.

'ABC123(BX3)' becomes 'ABC123'

'DEF456(BX12)' becomes 'DEF456'

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Replace:

```
(*)
```

with nothing.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  My issue is that I don't just want to replace the '(BX' with nothing. I also want to remove all characters after the '(BX'

Comment: @SMORF Then just change it to `(*` or `(BX*`.  The `*` is a wildcard for the `Replace`

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer ... not sure if it's the best solution but, it works. 
I can split the string at the point of the '(BX' and only leave only the string before the '(BX' ...

```
=LEFT(A2, FIND("(BX",A2)-1)
```